# $7^n$ contains a block of consecutive zeroes

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that there is a positive integer $n$ such that the decimal representation of $7^n$ contains a block of at least $m$ consecutive zeros, where $m$ is any given positive integer.

I will prove it more generally for any prime $p$. It is sufficient to find an $n$ such that $p^n$ begins with the number $100\ldots 0$ which has exactly $m$ zeroes. Thus, we are looking for $n$ and $k$ with $k < m$ such that $10^m 10^k \leq p^n < 10^k(10^m+1)$. This is equivalent to $m \leq n\log_{10}{p}-k < \log_{10}(10^m+1)$.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3):

Since $7$ is coprime to $10$, for each $k\geq 1$ we have $7^{\phi(10^k)}\equiv 1$ (mod $10^k$), where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

In other words, $7^{\phi(10^k)}-1$ is divisible by $10^k$. What does this tell you about the decimal expansion of $7^{\phi(10^k)}$?

Comment: Would this solution be correct: We know from Euler's Totient Theorem that since $7$ is coprime to $10$, for each $k \geq 1$ we have $7^{\varphi(10^k)} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^k}$. Thus, $7^{\varphi(10^k)}$ must end in at least $k-1$ zeroes.

Comment: Actually $7^{\phi(10^k)}$ ends in 1, but the $1$ is preceded by at least $k-1$ zeroes.

Comment: Isn't that what my solutions says? Oh I meant to say contains.

Comment: Your comment says $7^{\phi(10^k)}$ ends with $k-1$ zeros, but it actually ends with a $1$. Before this $1$ there are at least $k-1$ zeros.

Answer (score 1):

For short,
$$ 7^{2\cdot 10^n}\equiv 1\pmod{10^n} $$
gives a number with $n-1$ consecutive zeroes in the decimal representation.

Comment: How did you come up with $32 \cdot 10^n$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: $\varphi(10^k) = 2^{k+1}5^{k-1}$, hence: $$ 10^{2\cdot 2^k 5^{k-1}}\equiv 1\pmod{10}^k, $$ and by raising both terms to the fifth power...